# Using SVG from assets folder into component in component folder not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm new and still learning ReactJS, one issue that's stumping me is trying to use an SVG image I made in Vectornator from my assets folder to a header component in my component folder. It works fine when I made the mockup in HTML and I didn't had this issue when working on an Angular project last semester. Is there a fix or should I switch back to Angular and give up learning React lol. Also I'm using CRA since I just found out there's a lot of other ways to create a React app, chaos for a later date.

I don't know if it has any issue with folder structure because wherever I put the image it gives me this error.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg20E.png)

This is how my folder structure looks like
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJJIL.png)

And this is my code. I tried doing this through using an img tag and by making the SVG a react component but nothing works to display the image.

```
import DVLogo from "../assets/DVLogo.svg";
// import {ReactComponent as DVLogo} from "./assets/DVLogo.svg";

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header className="header">
            {/* <div>
                <DVLogo />
            </div> */}
            <img src={DVLogo} alt="Logo"/>
             <h2 className="header-name">DV</h2>
            <nav>
                <ul className="nav-links">
                    <li><a></a>Search</li>
                    <li><a></a>Collections</li>
                    <li><a></a>About</li>
                    <li><a></a>Decks</li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a className="login-btn"><button>Login</button></a>
        </header>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

When I use ../ instead of ./

[Error #2 part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHzPB.png)

[Error #2 part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns8XF.png)

Comment: Please post your code as code, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Completely forgot about that when posting the other images, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was create a component returning the actual SVG code and change the syntax of them to match the JSX.

### Examples:

`stroke-width` to `strokeWidth`

`style="fill-rule: nonzero;"` to `style={{ fillRule: "nonzero"}}`

`vectornator:layerName="card"` to  `vectornatorlayername="card"`

Below is pics of both for a more in-depth look at the differences if anyone is interested. Thank you guys for helping. Not changing majors yet!

[Original SVG file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mycSA.jpg)

[New SVG component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq1dh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are not in the correct directory.

When you import your image you need to:

```
import MyLogo from "../assets/DVLogo.sv" // Note the 2 dots (..)
```

If you are using the following format:

```
<img src={DVLogo} alt="Logo"/> // WRONG
```

You can not pass only DVLogo but also need the `src`:

```
<img src={DVLogo.src} alt="Logo"/> // CORRECT
```

Comment: So I did that and got a whole mess of an error pop up. I put it at the bottom of the question I posted.

Comment: Saw another issue when you're using `<img>` tag. See updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives me the new error from when changed "./" to "../", so I can't tell if the format you suggested worked :(